# how to center vertically text with adding/updating only css code and very small html code update

Tags: html, css, layout, center

I have some html code generated by Wordpress plugin and I want to center vertically the text on the right.I cannot change the HTML code because it's generated by plugin (I have to check if Im allowed to modify its soruce code). In HTML code only DIV tag can be swapped or modified in any way.

But my idea is if this text can be center vertically only by updating existing CSS class definitions and changing only starting and ending DIVs in HTML code?

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pu5cb3mo/4/)

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <a class="tptn_link" rel="bookmark" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=30">
        <img class="tptn_thumb" border="1" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" title="Post for TaxTips" alt="Post for TaxTips" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/top-10/timthum…2Ftaxhug%2Fimages%2Ffeatured-taxtips.png&w=60&h=60&zc=1&q=75"></img>
    </a>
    <span class="tptn_after_thumb">
        <a class="tptn_link" rel="bookmark" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=30">
            <span class="tptn_title">

                Post for TaxTips

            </span>
        </a>
        <span class="tptn_list_count">

            (14)

        </span>
    </span>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.tptn_thumb{
  margin-right: 10px;  

  float: left;
}



/* popular post title*/
.tptn_after_thumb{

}

.tptn_after_thumb:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `tptn_thumb` has a fixed height you can use `line-height: 42px;` on `tptn_title`

---

EDIT:

Sorry, read "vertically" instead of "horizontally". My solution is for a vertical alignment.

---

EDIT2:

You need to add this css code:

```
.tptn_title {
  line-height: 42px;
}
```

and remove the `line-height` from `.tptn_thumb{`

See the [updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pu5cb3mo/8/)

Comment: I fixed the post, I had one request for vertical and  one for  horizontal alignment:). Vertical is needed. Let me check it.

Comment: No, it's aligning image alt text (image is on left), I want to vertically allign text on right:) Your demo is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/pu5cb3mo/7/

Comment: Yes, exactly:) ... give some description.

Comment: Description for what?

Comment: I copies this one line,  to my code but some post has long title and it's displayed under image.

Comment: Need a fiddle for that!

Comment: For now I was able to cut off more that 20 character on plugin level. So text is centered and looks better:) but I would like to display whole text if possible.